Date Range Slicer Making in Power BI
Assume I have this table:



Project Name
Phase
Start Date
End Date




Project A
Plumbing
March 7th, 2022
September 11th, 2025


Project A
Renovation
September 13th, 2023
May 4th, 2025


Project A
Evaluation
September 13th, 2023
January 31st, 2026



So, I want to create a slicer visual that consists of year selection to filter a card or table visual.
I want this slicer works that when I choose 2024, the "Project A" will be shown in the card/table.
What kind of table transformation shall I do before I consumed it into the power bi that would let me provide such a slicer? or maybe there are some things that I can do inside the power bi by making a measurements or new column?
What I did was to unpivot the table (using pandas before I consumed it into power bi) into this:



Project Name
Phase
State
Date




Project A
Plumbing
Start
March 7th, 2022


Project A
Plumbing
End
September 11th, 2025


Project A
Renovation
Start
September 13th, 2023


Project A
Renovation
End
May 4th, 2025


Project A
Evaluation
Start
September 13th. 2023


Project A
Evaluation
End
January 31st, 2026



And then I make the slicer based on the date, but still, it won't solve the 2024 choice in the slicer.

I want this slicer works that when I choose 2024, the "Project A" will be shown in the card/table.
Can you explain the logic behind ?

Where's your Calendar table?
You can use CalendarAuto() to do it or use CALENDAR(MINX(FactTable,[DateColumn]),MAXX(FactTable,[DateColumn]))
and then wrap that in ADDCOLUMNS() to create the year, month, monthname, day, etc columns.
